# Program says input string is not in a correct format C#

Tags: c#

I tried to make a simple GPA calculator so i made my own function called assess which takes the grade as a string and returns the points as a double

```
double assess (ref string ppo)
    {
        string [] grade = new string [11] {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "F"};
        string [] num = new string [11] {"4", "3.67"," 3.33"," 3"," 2.67", "2.33", "2", "1.67", "1.33", "1"," 0"}; 
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
           if (ppo == grade [i]) 
           {
               ppo=num[i];
               break;
           }
        }
        return double.Parse(ppo, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    }
```

And it was working well on its own. I'd use the code and it would work perfectly, but then i put it in a loop and it kept giving me the same error saying Input string is not in a correct format

I took the code out of the loop, and it worked fine, but it doesn't work when i put it in the loop

```
Program prog=new Program();
        int num=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int z;
 for (z=0;z<num;z++)
        {
            point[z]=prog.assess(ref grade[z]);
        }
```

Comment: Then debug... but a breakpoint in the if and see what the value of ppo is after the `break`

Comment: Arent you looping 12 numbers (0, 1, 3, ..., 11), while you only have 11 numbers in your strings?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because some of your values of `num` array contains a white space character, and it can't be converted to `double`.

Remove the white spaces from the values of the `num` array, or change your code, including a `Trim()` on this line:

```
if (ppo == grade[i])
{
    ppo = num[i].Trim(); // Clean white spaces
    break;
}
```

As a good practice, you can also change your `for` loop, to use the length of the `grade` array, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < grade.Length; i++)
{
    if (ppo == grade[i])
    {
        ppo = num[i].Trim(); // Clean white spaces
        break;
    }
}
```